# BingAds API Soap Request

Tags: c#, soap, bing

I have been trying to use the BingAds Soap API call to get a keyword performance. But the following request falled for some reason. I would appreciate if someone can tell me where tyhe problem is.It returns the Internal 500 error.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

      string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope
      xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
      xmlns:v8='https://adcenter.microsoft.com/v8'
      xmlns:arr='https://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'>
      <soapenv:Header>
      <v8:UserName>xxx</v8:UserName>
      <v8:Password>xxx</v8:Password>
      <v8:DeveloperToken>xxx</v8:DeveloperToken>
      <v8:CustomerId>xxx</v8:CustomerId>
      <v8:CustomerAccountId>xxx</v8:CustomerAccountId>
      <v8:ApplicationToken></v8:ApplicationToken>
      </soapenv:Header>
      <soapenv:Body>
      <v8:SubmitGenerateReportRequest>
      <v8:ReportRequesti:type=""v8:KeywordPerformanceReportRequest""xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
      <v8:Format>Csv</v8:Format>
      <v8:Language>English</v8:Language>
      <v8:ReportName>MyReport</v8:ReportName>
      <v8:ReturnOnlyCompleteData>false</v8:ReturnOnlyCompleteData>
      <v8:Aggregation>Daily</v8:Aggregation>
      <v8:Columns>
      <v8:KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>AccountId</v8:KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>
      <v8:KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>AccountName</v8:KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>
      <v8:KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>Keyword</v8:KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>
      <v8:KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>KeywordId</v8:KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>
      <v8:KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>AdGroupName</v8:KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>
      <v8:KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>CostPerConversion</v8:KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>
      </v8:Columns>
      <v8:Scope>
      <v8:AccountIds>
      <arr:long>xxx</arr:long>
      </v8:AccountIds>
      </v8:Scope>
      <v8:Time>
      <v8:PredefinedTime>LastSevenDays</v8:PredefinedTime>
      </v8:Time>
      </v8:ReportRequest>
      </v8:SubmitGenerateReportRequest>
      </soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Envelope>";

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://adcenterapi.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/v8/Reporting/ReportingService.svc");

        req.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Accept = "text/xml";

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            writer.Write(xml);
        }

        WebResponse response1 = req.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response1.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        string responseData = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();


}
```

Comment: Try generating a soap client from the wsdl instead, Handling huge chunks of untyped, guesswork XML is rarely appropriate when there are other methods available.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the Arrays namespace should not be https.

xmlns:arr='http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'

Also you shouldn't need extra quotes around KeywordPerformanceReportRequest.
"v8:KeywordPerformanceReportRequest"

That should not impact the request, but is not necessary.

I hope this helps!

Eric Urban [MSFT Bing Ads UA]

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://adcenterapi.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/v8/Reporting/ReportingService.svc");
```

Shouldn't you have ?wsdl in the URL, like this:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://adcenterapi.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/v8/Reporting/ReportingService.svc?wsdl");
```

Comment: This seems not the issue. I fixed this URL. it still doesn't work.

Comment: No, that would just make it a request for the wsdl.